# text_field_tag with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I've a hard time with ActiveAdmin and their DSL. I'm using it to build my admin and at some point in a form I need to have a `text_field_tag`; I mean some fields which aren't related to the model I'm manipulating in the form which will be sent through with the model related data.

A custom text field basically. Nothing too crazy.

So I've built this

```
panel 'Send payment authorization' do
  active_admin_form_for EventPaymentAuthorization.new, url: { action: :send_event_payment_authorization } do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :body, as: :text

      f.text_field_tag :line_items_label
      f.text_field_tag :line_items_amount

      f.input :fees_in_cents, as: :select, collection: [:free, :automatic], prompt: true, selected: :automatic
    end
    f.actions do
      f.action :submit, label: 'Create payment authorization'
    end
  end
end
```

The `f.text_field_tag` get simply ignored by ActiveAdmin. Why is that? It doesn't raise any error, but it doesn't show either.

The reason I need custom unrelated inputs is because `line_items` in my example is a JSONB with values such as `[{amount: 0.0, label: 'Hello'}]` and I don't believe it can be processed through Formtastic or ActiveAdmin natively. It's also always good to be able to create  custom inputs when sending data.

Comment: Try `f.text_field` instead.

Comment: f.text_field is for model backed field

Answer (score 0):

Working with JSON in ActiveAdmin is a bit tricky, it largely depends on your needs. The quickest way to get going is to use the [activeadmin_json_editor](https://github.com/udacity/activeadmin_json_editor) gem. I also wrote a blog entry on [working with JSON in ActiveAdmin](http://www.lixy.tech/blog/2019/05/active-admin-jsonb-forms.html) with more detail and another approach, which may better suit your needs, as it appears you are not just working with arbitrary data into your JSON field.